# does git create a tag with commit

Tags: git, version-control, tags, branch

In SVN everytime we commit anything, a tag gets created by itself. and later we can replace/update code with that tag.

does git create a tag with every commit(for public repositories) ?

In short , is there any checkpoint/ID/Number created by git , which I can use to track the changes made by the commits, later? 
Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean, whenever you commit, git creates a hash for you to use to go back to that particular commit.

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it as answer. And it will also 

benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

Commits in git have a hash that is used as a commit ID and every commit has one.

Tag is a separate thing and without manually calling [git tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) or without some level of automation ([git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), steps in your CI pipeline) a tag will not be created.